# How to change attribute "autoplay" in a post

Tags: wordpress, autoplay

I have an issue, 
My WordPress blog embeds a video from Imgur. It autoplay when it is loaded. It also loops automatically. And it works perfectly with this embed HTML.
However, it doesn't stop when we scroll it out of screen. How to stop it when  scrolled out? thank

```
<center><video style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls" width="450" height="auto"><source src="https://i.imgur.com/84FAg6j.mp4" /></video></center>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have just added `id` to the video tag and I have just used jQuery's play and pause options based on the scroll position. Hope this will help you.

```js
var sec_position = $('#sec').offset().top;
var vid = document.getElementById('video');
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var window_position = window.pageYOffset;
  if (sec_position < window_position) {
    vid.pause();
  } else {
    vid.play();
  }
});
```

```css
#sec {
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center><video id="video" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls" width="450" height="auto">
    <source src="https://i.imgur.com/84FAg6j.mp4" /></video></center>
<div id="sec"></div>
```

Comment: It have run code snipptet and it work as my expectation. However, I am not familiar with wordpress. Can you help me how to apply it. Thank you

Comment: Thank you... video tag code paste to your like a page then js code paste to footer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery:

HTML

adding an ID your element:

```
<video id="myvideo" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;" preload="auto" 
autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" controls="controls" width="450" height="auto">
```

JS

calling pause on scroll

```
$('#myvideo').bind("ended", function(){ 
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".big-div").offset().top
}, 2000);
});


function isInView(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();          
  return !(rect.top > $(window).height() || rect.bottom < 0);   // visible?
 }

 $(document).on("scroll", function() {
  $( "#myvideo" ).each(function() {
    if (isInView($(this)[0])) {                    // visible?
      if ($(this)[0].paused) $(this)[0].play();    // play if not playing
    }
    else {
      if (!$(this)[0].paused) $(this)[0].pause();  // pause if not paused
    }
  });  
});
```

CSS

```
.big-div{
  height:1000px;
  background:orange;
 }
```

Don't forget to include jQuery before initializing the function (in the header)

```
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
```

check out my example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/REanzIzi7Pb33UPHLJo9?p=preview

Scroll down and up again after some time to see the video was paused.

Comment: It is that what I want :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [isInViewport](https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport) jQuery plugin as below:

```
$('video').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":in-viewport")) {
        $(this)[0].play();
    } else {
        $(this)[0].pause();
    }
})
```